# Blockchain Wallet cannot send ethereum

Tags: blockchain, wallets

I am starting to be really fed up with this (shi**y) wallet.

First of (unrelated problem) it started to show wrong ethereum balance (zero) on the dashboard, probably showing the balance of "trading" wallet instead of private wallet (all of sudden).

But now i tried to send some ethers and the button Send does nothing !!!

Until now it worked great. Or maybe i never actually tried to withdraw anything from this wallet.

What the heck is happening?

[image]

Doesn't matter if you set $50 or eth value to be transfered, the Send button does nothing either.

Comment: Do you have some kind of recovery phrase? And which app is this?

Comment: Blockhain Wallet app

Answer (score 0):

It was some problem of their api.. the button was disabled, but later it started working.. at least..